# Second order derivatives of a function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

We have to use the Hessian to calculate the second order derivatives of a function. While that is okay if the function is mapped from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, how does one proceed if it is mapped from $\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, where $m > 1$? How does one take the derivative of f with respect to each variable when f is itself in more than one dimension?

For example, if there is a function f : $\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with $(x,y)$ mapped to $(x^2 + y, y^3, \cos(y))$, how does one calculate the Hessian?

Thank you

Comment: Do it component-wise.

Comment: Then how does the hessian look like? Normally it would look like this: [del^2(f)/delx^2 del^2(f)/delx dely;del^2(f)/dely^2 del^2(f)/delx dely ] . Now how will it look like?

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you are looking for is the following:

Let $\vec{f}(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} u(x,y) \\ v(x,y) \\ w(x,y)\end{pmatrix}$. Its "Hessian" is simply the "vector-valued matrix"

$$ H_{\vec{f}} = \begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} u_{xx} \\ v_{xx} \\ w_{xx}\end{pmatrix} & 
\begin{pmatrix} u_{xy} \\ v_{xy} \\ w_{xy}\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix} u_{yx} \\ v_{yx} \\ w_{yx}\end{pmatrix} &
\begin{pmatrix} u_{yy} \\ v_{yy} \\ w_{yy}\end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix} $$

where $ u_{xy} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y} u$ etc. Note that each entry of the "matrix" is now a vector in its own right.

Comment: So to apply it to any vector, we need two vectors p and q, right?

Comment: What do you mean "to apply it to any vector"? If you are trying to compute the second order derivative in the mixed directions $\vec{p},\vec{q}$, you plug it in as $\vec{p}^T H_{\vec{f}} \vec{q}$ which will return a _vector_.

Answer (score 1):

The importance of the Hessian comes from the following fact:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces, and let $L(X,Y)$ denote the space of *continuous* linear maps from $X$ to $Y$. There is a canonical isomorphism (and actually an isometry) $$L(X,L(X,Y)) \simeq \operatorname{Bil}(X\times X\to Y),$$ where Bil is the set of *bilinear* continuous maps from $X \times X$ to $Y$.

Since the second derivative belongs to $L(X,L(X,Y))$, we can identify it with a bilinear map. If $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, then the bilinear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ can be represented by $(n\times n)$ matrices, and you get the Hessian matrix. If the codomain of $f$ has higher dimension, matrices no longer suffice. I guess you'd need *tensors*. See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Vector-valued_functions).

**Additional material:** assume that $\mathbf{f} \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is of class $C^2$. Then the second differential at $\mathbf{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ acts like $$\mathrm{d}^2 \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_0)\colon (\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2) \mapsto \sum_{i,j=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}} \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial x_{j}}(\mathbf{x}_0) v_{1,i}v_{2,j}$$ on the generic vectors $\mathbf{v}_1$, $\mathbf{v}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $v_{1,i}$, $v_{2,j}$ are the components of $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$, respectively.

Comment: I can't understand how to start solving for the matrix. Could you please give me an idea as to how to do it. I need to calculate the second order derivative of the aforementioned function.

Comment: If you codomain has dimension higher than $1$, there is *no* hessian matrix at all. The second derivative is a tensor of order $3$; you can compute the components of this tensor by second order partial derivatives of $f$, but the action of the second derivative of $f$ is the action of a tensor. Remember that you are differentiating twice a *vector field*, and this is not that trivial.

Comment: So how does this tensor look in this case? I have not done tensor theory, actually. How does one calculate the second derivative of the function?

Comment: I've added an explicit formula for the second differential.